# Using spring session scope without session

Tags: java, spring

I have web application where I defined session scoped UserDetail. The problem is that I also have some Quartz jobs that should use UserDetail bean. When job is run I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userDetails': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Inside job I need to inject some "technical user" details. Is it possible to properly handle situation when session is not present? Maybe any conditional injection?

**EDIT 1**

To clarify. I dont want to have session in my job service. This job modifies data and some audit log based on user data is saved to database. Normally user data comes from session but in job I need to provide some "static" technical user data. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to inject session scoped bean into singleton bean?

Comment: A session only exists in a web application and when there is an active session, so no you cannot have a session without a session active. Looks to me you are approaching it wrong...

Comment: I want to have singleton bean when running job.

Comment: Yes, session scoped bean into singleton bean. Proxy is injected inside singleton. Bean is always present so I cant switch behavior depending on bean presence.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz does not know anything about "sessions", so if you want your background job to know the user that submitted the job, **you** have to pass that information to the job, likely in the DataMap of the trigger.